# Ember Application Alerts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I currently have an application with the following application and view. I want to be able to flash these notifications during various points in my application. My current emberscripts file includes

```
class Candidate.ApplicationController extends Ember.ArrayController
    alerts: Ember.Object.create
        success: [
            'TaDa!'
            'Here we go!'
        ]
        error: [
            'What did you do now!?'
        ]

Candidate.AlertsView = Ember.View.extend
    templateName: 'views/alerts'

Candidate.AlertView = Ember.View.extend
    templateName: 'views/alert'

    class: (->
        return 'alert alert-' + @type
    ).property()

    close: ->
        @$().slideUp 'normal', =>
            @destroy()
```

And my handlebars for the `view/alerts` looks like this:

```
{{#each alerts.success}}
    {{view Candidate.AlertView messageBinding=this type="success"}}
{{/each}}
```

And the `views/alert`:

```
<div {{bindAttr class="view.class" }}>
    <i class="icon-remove-sign"></i>
    <button type="button" class="close" {{action 'close' target='view'}}>×</button>
    {{view.message}}
</div>
```

Right now this works fine for the initialized value, but has a few issues.

1. It does not allow me to add new alerts
2. The close function does not remove the alert from the alerts object on the application controller

How would I go about making this this a bit closer to a session flash alert message bag like what would be available on the server?

Here's a JSBin of the current code: http://jsbin.com/ejAS/1/

Comment: Refer this : http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/2014/05/01/alert-messages-in-ember-apps.html

Answer (score 1):

you can look at this example using an ember component http://jsbin.com/AQuQILI/8/edit?html,js,output
I hope this may help you

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. Please don't just link to a website. Include relevant information in your answer. This helps reduce damage from link rot and creates a better answer. See ["Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really 'good answers'?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/197656) and ["How do I write a good answer?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Bootstrap for Ember](https://github.com/ember-addons/bootstrap-for-ember) For a more complete notifications component.

It supports auto fadein / fade out of messages, hovering a mouse over a notification causes it not to fade out so the user can have more time to read it, show time / fade in / fade out times can be configured, etc...

**Demo:**

http://ember-addons.github.io/bootstrap-for-ember/dist/#/show_components/notifications

Comment: Cool! I looked at it briefly and didn't find a good example for some reason. I am going to integrate Bootstrap for Ember in my project soon as some of the eventing is becoming a bit much to work with...

Comment: the alerts in Bootstrap for Ember rely on Ember.CollectionView which is far from ideal and likely to be deprecated soon. I would recommend against using them. Try a component example instead, there are some offered in this page.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more research on passing around data and understanding controllers more, I think I've actually gone with this approach.

http://jsbin.com/uhel/6/edit?html,js

While I'd really like to do the fade in and out, this seems to get the job done quite well.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Fab. Alerts should be constructed by Components not Views or Controllers and certainly not by Bootstrap.js. This means we will have greater "Ember world control" of the widget.

There's another component example answered here: [How can I make an Alert Notifications component using Ember.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070102/how-can-i-make-an-alert-notifications-component-using-ember-js/)